# $\sup A = \inf B$ implies $\forall\varepsilon>0.\exists a\in A, b\in B. b-a<\varepsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $A, B$ two sets such that $\sup A = \inf B$. Is it right that:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0. \exists a\in A, b\in B. b-a<\varepsilon \quad ?
$$

The question doesn't mention the sets are densed, but that was probably the intention.

I think the claim is true.
for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we are able to choose $a\in A$ such that $\sup A - a < {\varepsilon \over 3}$ and $b\in B$ such that $b - \inf B < {\varepsilon \over 3}$.

And so, the distance is ${2 \over 3\varepsilon} < \varepsilon$.

**We can choose $a, b$ as mentioned because those sets are densed.**

Is that right? (Or am I being silly here? because the proof is almost trivial).

Comment: That's correct. You could just choose $\epsilon/2$ and $\epsilon/2$ so that the distance is less than $\epsilon$ which would simplify things. (And use the triangle rule if you need more rigor)

Comment: What do you mean by "densed" ? dense set ? This has nothing to do with density. You can always choose such $a$ and $b$ by definition of $sup$ and $inf$, because if not, then $\forall a \in A, a \leq supA-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but that would be an upper bound that is strictly smaller than supA, contradicting the definition of sup. The same holds for $B$. Apart this, the spirit of the proof is correct

Comment: As an aside, it would be better if your title was something more descriptive than the beginning of every problem in real analysis.

Comment: There is one special case that needs to be observed. Often one writes $\sup\emptyset =-\infty$ and  $\inf B=-\infty$ if $b$ is not bounded from below. Or $\sup A=+\infty$ if $A$ is not bounded from above and $\sup\emptyset=+\infty$. If one allows these cases, they provide counterexamples. (Officially, $\inf$ and $\sup$ do not exist for these sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, but being a bit silly.
The thing you are being silly about is the "denseness" thing.
This is unnecessary; definition of the supremum and infemum imply that for any
positive $\epsilon$,
there is an element at most $\epsilon$ away from the supremum (or infemum) in the set.
(This element may, of course, be equal to the supremum or infemum itself.)
In particular this is true for $\frac{\epsilon}{3} > 0$.

Also note Hagen von Eitzen's comment: you must assume the supremum and infemum are finite real numbers for this to work.

Comment: Thank you. the definition for sup/inf made it clear to me.

Comment: @AnnieOK You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. You can always make that choice, by definition of $\sup A$ (if that's not a maximum then you can choose elements at distance less that $\varepsilon$, else $supA-\varepsilon$ would be a smaller $\sup A$). 
FALSE( Denseness is needed if you have to choose an element with distance *exactly* $\varepsilon$ )

Comment: Denseness of $A$ or $B$ does *not* imply an element with distance exactly $\epsilon$.

Comment: To give an example for Goos' comment: Let $A$ be negative irrationals and $B$ be positive rationals; then there is no $x\in A,y\in B$ with $|x-y|=1$.

Comment: Oh you're right, I was thinking about another notion